# How to inject cxf bus a custom JAXB context?

Tags: web-services, jaxb, cxf

I have a server exposing multiple web services.
The objects of the services are scattered in several packages.
From my understanding if you have inheritance and a service can return a number of possible sub classes you need to use the @XmlSeeAlso on the base class which adds unnecessary dependencies and complexity.
For both performance and dynamic configuration reasons I want to create myself the JAXB context which will be used by the CXF client / server services.
This way I can avoid the unnecessary dependencies and manage the context myself.
I prefer specifying it once on the bus level, but if that isn't possible I guess controlling it on the service level will be good enough.
Thanks in advance,
  avner